# How to calculate the probability for pattern that violates "control chart rules" to occur?

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, control-chart

I am going to host a training session to teach healthcare staff how to use control chart (c-chart to be specific), and I need to tell that why these rules ([Western Electric Rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Electric_rules#Zone_rules)) are so called rules that when pattern is matched, outbreak can be considered as a probability.

I have read the article "[Control Charts 101: A Guide to Health Care Applications](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11372500)" a bit and it teaches me a bit, saying the chance for one data point to exceed UCL is less than 0.5%, I can calculate that using the following R code without problem:

```
1-pnorm(3, mean=0, sd=1)
[1] 0.001349898
```

I have written the following R code to verify the same thing in c-chart (i.e. poisson rather than normal distribution), for lambda ranged from 1.0 to 100.0

```
UCL <- integer(0)

for (loop.UCL in (1:1000))
    {lambda <- loop.UCL/10
     result <- 1-ppois(lambda+ceiling(sqrt(lambda)*3),lambda)
     UCL <- c(UCL, result)
    }

summary(UCL)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu. 
0.0009679 0.0016160 0.0018260 0.0019960 0.0021220 
     Max. 
0.0134600
```

I think I can handle the first Western Electric Rules, but I am puzzled for the second and third.

Can anyone give me some insight or hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two figures of merit in control charting are (1) the expected length of time the process will appear to remain in control when in fact it is; and (2) the expected length of time it takes for an OOC condition to be detected after the process first moves out of control.

Under the usual assumptions--iid normally distributed values, no serial correlation, etc--we can reduce the first case to analyses of correlated coin flipping experiments.  An accurate solution takes some work; people usually run simulations.  However, each rule by itself has a simple interpretation:

**Rule 1** characterizes each measurement by whether it lies beyond the interval $[-3\sigma, 3\sigma]$ (with 0.27% probability) or not.  It corresponds, then, to flipping a coin with $\Pr(\text{heads})$ =0.0027 and we want to know the expected number of flips before a "heads" (OOC condition) is observed.

**Rule 2**  characterizes each measurement by whether it exceeds $2\sigma$ or falls below $-2\sigma$.  This is like a "3-sided" coin: a multinomial distribution.  One face says "above $2 \sigma$" and occurs with probability 2.28%.  Let's call this "heads 1".  Another face says "below $-2 \sigma$" and also occurs with probability 2.28%.  Call this "heads 2".  The third face says "between $-2 \sigma$ and $2 \sigma$" and occurs with probability 95.45%.  The analogous question concerns the expected number of flips with this coin before a sequence of two heads *of the same type* is observed.  The calculation might not be easy, but it's easy to see this event is fairly rare: the chance of either head appearing is just 4.55%, but given that it just appeared, the chance that a head of the same type immediately follows it is only 2.28%.  Thus, if we only had a pair of throws to consider, an OOC event of this type would occur with probability 4.55% * 2.28% * 2 (multiply by 2 to account for both types of "heads") = 0.21%.

**Rule 3** can be analyzed in a similar manner (but is more complicated).

Note that the rules are interrelated: a single observation can violate two or even all three rules, even though all preceding observations were in control.  However, this has fairly low probability of occurring, so to a good approximation we can assume the rules are mutually exclusive (allowing us to sum their probabilities).

The purpose of rules 2 and 3 is to reduce the expected time needed to detect an OOC condition caused by a systematic change in the mean.  How they accomplish this is intuitively clear: a small increase in mean, for example, only slightly increases the chance of triggering rule 1, but greatly increases the chance of triggering rule 2.  For example, a one-sd increase in mean increases the chance of a rule 1 violation to $1 - \Phi(3-1) + \Phi(-3-1)$ = 2.28%, which is expected to take about 1/0.028 = 44 time steps to detect, but a rule 3 violation (four in a row above 1 sd) now has slightly greater than a $(1/2)^4$ = 6.25% chance of occurring, which will be detected almost three times quicker (around 16 time steps).

**In summary**, these rules can be understood by analyzing sequences of coin flips (or die rolls); each one corresponds to an event (or sequence of events) that is sufficiently rare that a process in control will go for a long time without triggering an OOC signal; and the combined set of rules is formulated to be able to detect relatively small shifts of the mean as quickly as possible.